# Passing coordinate array to main (openGL, C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opengl

I am trying to pass coordinates of a cube to a main function in C++. This function is located in a seperate cpp file and the method looks like this:

```
 GLfloat * Cube::getVertices()
 {
 // Set up our vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
   GLfloat  vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};
// GLfloat *vert = vertices;
  return vertices;
}
```

In the main method I do this

```
 Cube cube1;
 GLfloat * vertices;
 vertices = cube1.getVertices();
```

Whenever my coordinates are in main the cube comes out correctly but when it is in this seperate method it seems like I am getting addresses instead of values and no square appears. Does it have something to do with the way I pass the array?

Comment: Is there some really good reason you need to use an array rather than a `vector`?

Comment: Well, I do believe you're returning a pointer to a temporary array so that could be a slight issue.

Comment: I need it to be an array because I am binding it to buffers that call for an array @Jerry Coffin.

Comment: You can return a `vector` and take the address of the first element when you need to treat it like an array (but be sure the vector doesn't get destroyed before you're done using it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you seem to have constant data that you want to return. Make it static and const. Then it won't go out of scope.

```
const GLfloat* Cube::getVertices() {
    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Data here.
    };
    return vertices;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does it have something to do with the way I pass the array?

You don't pass an array. You pass a pointer. To a local array, those lifetime ends when the function is left. What you have here is just undefined behavior.

Comment: How can I make the second array not temporary if I don't want to initialize it in main?

Comment: Oh silly me, I think I need to allocate the array with new.. Is that right?